# Why is this command not working properly?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm working on a one command creation, Magical Weapons, and I'm currently working on a weapon called Black-Hole-In-A-Box. The idea is when you right-click with it, it clears all the blocks in a 5x5x5 box around you. So, I have this command (in a command block):

```
/execute @p ~ ~ ~ fill ~5 ~5 ~5 minecraft:air
```

but when I run it, I get this error message:

```
Failed to execute fill ~5 ~5 ~5 minecraft:air
```

But I don't know why it's not working. It should. I've worked for hours on this and I've tried tons of variations. What is the proper command to fill a 5x5x5 box around me with air?

Comment: You should probably test execute commands in normal command blocks or chat, that way you get a clearer error message. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fill needs two sets of coordinates, one for each corner of the box you want to fill. Try this:

```
/execute @p ~ ~ ~ fill ~-2.5 ~-2.5 ~-2.5 ~2.5 ~2.5 ~2.5 minecraft:air
```

Comment: Just a question: what is 2.5 equal to: 2 blocks or 3?

Comment: @hyperviper11 Neither. -2.5 to 2.5 on each axis makes it 5 blocks, centered around the player.

Answer (score -1):

try the command /fill ~5 ~5 ~5 ~ ~ ~ air

Comment: Hi Elyiana, welcome to Arqade! Could you perhaps elaborate on your command and what might be the issue with the current command in the question?